# How do I count and visualize the amount of how often a unit was seized respectively released and the of the simulation time?

Tags: anylogic

I want to create a plot which visualize how often a unit was released. But unfortunately I have no idea how I can do this. Can anyone please help me? My process graph looks like this. I want to count how often depots were released and visualize the data in a graph.
[My Process Graph looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScKUu.png)

I added on the resource pool the command "unit.timesReleased++;" On Release and add a Variable "timesReleased" in the agent workstation. Now I want to collect the count of how often the depot is released in a plot.
[Variable in Agent Workstation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiTfW.jpg)
[ResourcePool Depot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWZcC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to just put the plot into your `WorkStation` agent next to the counter and let it plot the counter directly.

Then, just navigate to the individual `WorkStation` agents at runtime to see it for each.

Else, have a plot on Main and regularly make it loop across all `WorkStation` agents and sum their counters. You can also create a statistic on the `WorkStation` agents if you define them as a separate population

Comment: Hello @Benjamin thank you very much for your help, but I do not really understand what do you mean by putting the plot into the Workstation agent next to the counter? I think with counter you mean the waitingAshelves block on my process graph or?

Comment: Drag the plot next to the variable `timesReleased`

Comment: Thank you @Benjamin!

Comment: If the answer was useful, pls upvote it, helps future users with similar issues, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote